# IIS7.5 - Hosting ASP.NET MVC app and ColdFusion app under one domain

Tags: hosting, iis-7.5, web-hosting, coldfusion, asp.net-mvc

We are developing and deploying an ASP.NET MVC app while will provide new functionality yet there are still parts of the ColdFusion app we still need to live under the same domain.  How can we set this up in IIS?  The ColdFusion app is setup and functioning in IIS already.  Have considered URL Rewrite but there are a large number of URLs to consider.  Any advice other than rewriting the rest of the ColdFusion app tonight are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. Your ASP.NET files will have an ".asp" extension and your ColdFusion files will have a ".cfm" extension. IIS will call the appropriate handler for you without any special setup (that is normal functionality). If you do not want to specify the file name in the url then the default document setting will take over. Again, IIS will handle this for you. One file name will have precedence over the other, either default.asp or default.cfm, depending on how you set it up in IIS. So what is not working for you?

Comment: You are exactly correct, Miguel. And after I asked this question we actually merged the code into a single directory and tried this and it worked splendidly. Thank you for answering the same and I hope this answers it for someone else in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this question someone on our team merged the site code (ColdFusion and ASP.NET MVC) and let IIS handlers take care of running them both.